# examine the exit code of processes launched in parallel from a script

Tags: bash

Say I have the following bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
process-1&
process-2&
process-3&
```

I have two questions:

1. how can I check at the end of my script that all processes exited with an exit code of 0 ?
2. how can my script "wait" until all launched processes have finished and then do a concluding `echo` (perhaps informing the user of the exit codes)?

Comment: Couldn't you can use `wait` on each process sequentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the bash builtin `wait`.
Three times `wait -n`, checking the exit status each time.

From [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html):

```
    wait [-n] [n ...]
           Wait  for  each  specified child process and return its termination
           status.  Each n may be a process ID or a job  specification;  if  a
           job  spec is given, all processes in that job's pipeline are waited
           for.  If n is not given, all currently active child  processes  are
           waited  for,  and  the  return status is zero.  If the -n option is
           supplied, wait waits for any job to terminate and returns its  exit
           status.   If  n specifies a non-existent process or job, the return
           status is 127.  Otherwise, the return status is the exit status  of
           the last process or job waited for.
```